# CloudFront usage in Unity3d

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-cloudfront

Searching for use examples of CloudFront in Unity and can't find it.
Can I use stream video from **CloudFront** in **Unity3d**?

Comment: This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` Please refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @derHugo this problem is specific, not general since AWS has this module. I highly doubt that in the recommended section people would answer me. 
I put the right tags, so hoping for a solution here from highly professional people that had experience of working with this specific problem that I faced.

Comment: Which media protocol do you want to use?

Comment: @MarcelDumont simple https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can use **CloudFront** in **Unity** at the moment.
The best way to do it is to *stream your video from S3*.
It worked for me and if you are searching for this kind of solutions - just use Amazon S3.